# Welches Geschlecht hat "Zamperl"?

Tags: gender, dialect, bavarian

Für Nichtbayern, mit [Zamperl](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamperl) bezeichnet man kleine Hunde.

Es ist mir nur nicht gelungen herauszufinden, ob es "das Zamperl" oder "der Zamperl" heißt.

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zamperl - Jetzt bin ich ein bißchen verwundert, warum es Dir nicht gelungen ist, am offensichtlichsten Ort nachzuschauen ;)

Comment: @john Smithers. Da hatte ich wohl Tomaten auf den Augen. Tatsächlich war ich nämlich auf genau der Seite.

Comment: Dann nehm ich mal an, Du hattest Dich vertippt. Oder die Duden-Redaktion folgt Takkat und nimmt seine Vorschläge in den Duden auf - ad hoc :P

Comment: @JohnSmithers: excellent aber sie geht etwas zurück.

Answer (score 13):

Wie im Schriftdeutsch verwandelt sich auch bei den [bairischen Dialekten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte#Der_Diminutiv) das Geschlecht zu Neutrum sobald ein Diminutiv gebildet wird:

> Wie im übrigen deutschen Sprachgebiet wandeln Diminutivsuffixe den Genus in neutrales Geschlecht - außer bei bestimmten Formen der Eigennamen, im Unterschied zum Deutschen; hier drückt die Unterdrückung des Genuswechsels eindeutig eine positiv-affektive Konnotation aus. <sup>Quelle [Bayrisch Lernen](http://www.bayrisch-lernen.de/grammatik/grammatik.html)</sup>

Somit handelt es sich um

> Das Zamperl, ***n.***

Hier noch ein Zitat aus einer renommierten Wochenzeitung:

> *"Ist **das** Zamperl nicht schwerer als fünf Kilo (inklusive Tragebox), kann **es** in der Kabine mitfliegen."* <sup>[Die Zeit Online](http://www.zeit.de/1988/45/herbstzeitlose)</sup>

Und aus einer bayrischen Tageszeitung:

> *"Wenn das Zamperl etwa Heimweh und Sehnsucht nach seinem Herrchen habe, müsse man sich besonders intensiv kümmern."* <sup>[Süddeutsche](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/muenchen/luxusherberge-fuer-zamperl-auf-den-hund-gekommen-1.377081)</sup>

Comment: Wie ist es dann mit: Im Münchner Olympiajahr 1972 fand der typische Zamperl Verwendung als Maskottchen der 20. Sommerspiele in der Bayerischen Landeshauptstadt. (aus obigem Wikipediaartikel)

Comment: Eine *"eindeutige positive-affektive Konnotation"* vielleicht? Keine Ahnung (bin kein Bayer), aber ich würde zunächst erstmal auf einen Fehler im Wikipedia Artikel tippen.

Comment: Ich nehme an, dass das Bayrische auch gewissen Regeln folgt, von daher ist *das Stamperl* mir ein bisschen geläufiger - und das ist auch Neutrum. Die Regel dürfte eine ähnliche sein, wie die, nach der *Mädchen* im Hochdeutschen als Diminutiv auch Neutrum ist.

Answer (score 4):

Maßgeblich, weil kompetenter als Duden oder Wikipedia, ist wohl der Sprachwissenschaftler Ludwig Zehetner. In dessen Standard-Lexikon "Bairisches Deutsch" heißt es "Der Zamperl, seltener: das Zamperl"

Comment: Naja, ein einzelner Fachgebietswissenschaftler vs. ein Standardfachbuch + die größte peerreviewte Kollaboration der Welt? Da würde ich die Frage, wer maßgeblicher oder kompetenter ist, nicht so ungestützt entscheiden wollen :) Einzelne Wissenschaftler irren sich ständig. Das ist praktisch die Berufsdefinition.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Wobei bedacht werden muss, wie alt der Ausdruck ist: es ist ohne weiteres moeglich, dass die Originalform _der_ verwendete, und sich _das_ erst spaeter eingebuergert hat. Kommt immer wieder vor.

Answer (score 1):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zamperl) und [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zamperl) (die wahrscheinlich voneinander abgeschrieben haben) ist das Zamperl ein Neutrum.

[Takkats Ausführungen](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3058/161) ist also uneingeschränkt zuzustimmen.